# How to make this form do two things (AJAX and PHP mail) on submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

Both of these form submission functions work individually but not if I have them both executing at the same time.

```
<form action=""  method="post" id="timesheet" >
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form> 


<script>
 //first, post results to a Google Spreadsheet 
  $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
     var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url: url,  //google sheet URL
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data : $form.serializeArray()
      });      
    }); 
</script>  


<?php
  // then email the user their response
      if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

     // standard PHP mail function (some code left out)
        $subject = "WORK TIMESHEET SUBMITTED";
        mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers); 
     }
?>
```

Comment: Because the form submit will cancel any running ajax requests, as you will be performing a page transition.  You'd want to delay the submit until the ajax is done.  *Or*, work the mail logic into the ajax request, or vise versa, so it happens as a single unit of work.

Comment: why does your comment in the code say "post results to a Google Spreadsheet" when you use GET?

Answer (score 7):

The AJAX is not finished, because the form submission is faster than the AJAX.

If you want to do both, the request and then the form submission, you can accomplish it like this:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission
     var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url: url,  //google sheet URL
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data : $form.serializeArray(),
            success: () => {
                $("#timesheet").submit(); // submit the form when the ajax is done
            }
      });      
    });
```

Answering to the OP's comment:

The problem may be, that, if `enable_post_data_reading` is off in the php.ini file, the `$_POST` variable is not populated. To fix this, please try using `php://input` instead of `$_POST`:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$response = json_decode($data, true ); // True converts to array; blank converts to object
$submit = $response["submit"];

if ($submit) {
    // Your Logic for creating the email
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. still doesn't seem to work. The AJAX goes through but not the PHP mail function

Comment: You only shared a tiny bit of PHP code witch clearly is not faulty

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. I didn't include my full PHP snippet but like I said, the mail function works on its own when the jQuery form submit function is commented out. Not sure what I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

Do a SUBMIT chained to the onclick event.

```
//first, post results to a Google Spreadsheet 
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
 var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: url,  //google sheet URL
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data : $form.serializeArray()
  });
//Then, chain a submit!
}).submit();
```