# AJAX not executing php script

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am attempting to write an application that interacts with a library and gets values from it, and I can't seem to figure out how to get a php script to execute when a button is clicked.

Index.html

```
Chapter: <input type="text" name="chapter"><br>
Section: <input type="text" name="section"><br>
Problem: <input type="text" name="problem"><br>
<input type="button" class="button" name="insert" value="Get Input" 
onClick="doStuff()"/>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
function doStuff()
{
var v1 = document.getElementById('chapter').value;
var v2 = document.getElementById('section').value;
var v3 = document.getElementById('problem').value;

 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "get-data.php",
 data: {chapter:v1,section:v2,problem:v3},
 success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
  }

  });
}
</script>
```

get-data.php

```
<?php

    function doit()
    {
        $chapter=$_GET['chapter'];
        $section=$_GET['section'];
        $problem=$_GET['problem'];
        $command = "python proc.py init $chapter $section $problem";
        $output = exec($command);
        echo $output; 
    }
    doit()
    ?>
```

the python script is confirmed to be working, and the php script is confirmed to be working when executed by using `<form action="get-data.php">` but it always redirects to a simple page where the output is `echo` to.

Comment: Your PHP is trying to access GET parameters, but your ajax request was a POST.

Comment: There is a missing ; after `doit()`. On top of that, your code is extremely dangerous. Anyone, who can access the script on your server, can run commands on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the variables as if they were passed to the PHP by GET request while using POST, change the PHP to the following. Use `filter_input` to apply some safeguards:

```
<?php

    function doit()
    {
        $chapter=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'chapter');
        $section=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'section');
        $problem=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'problem');
        $command = "python proc.py init $chapter $section $problem";
        $output = exec($command);
        echo $output; 
    }
    doit();
    ?>
```

**Note**: These safeguards are probably not enough, you should make sure that no dangerous keywords can be passed to the script.

Comment: I made all these changes but upon clicking the button, nothing is executed and no alert appears.

Comment: Please read the last part [of my answer to a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49761518/6634591), what is the  enable_post_data_reading flag in your PHP.ini file set to?

Comment: I set `enable_post_data_reading` to `On` and its still not doing anything.

Comment: Yes, when accessing each item do I just do `$chapter = $response["chapter"];``$section = $response["section"];``$problem = $response["problem"];``$command = "python proc.py init $chapter $section $problem";`

Comment: Please try posting to it using a program like Postman or cUrl, and try if it works with those. Php can be *very* particular about what data it accepts. You could also try building a FormData Object on the client side instead of sending JSON

Answer (score 0):

You should receive values in php page by using $_POST not $_GET, because in ajax request that you wrote you are using type = "POST".

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered, AJAX sends data using HTTP/POST, while you are using $_GET.

However, if for some reason (like manual testing) you want the page to handle both parameters from a POST and a GET request, you can use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php